# Select Query for specific sum

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I want to subtract Total Amount - Paid Amount amount in first table (tutar) paid amount in second table (odemetutari)

How can I make this for grid view and show tckimlikno,adisoyadi,calculated new amount

```
SELECT  sum(tutar) AS IcraTutari ,tckimlikno
  FROM Om_icra_infos
  where tckimlikno=tckimlikno
  group by  tckimlikno
```

First here  find same tutar with same tckimlikno

and second here

```
SELECT sum(odemetutari)
FROM Om_icraodeme_infos
where tckimlikno=tckimlikno
```

I want to his for each row  show first tutar - second odemetutari = calculatedamount and show this in new selected view

like this:

```
tckimlikno  calculatedamount
1111111111  111,22   ( tutar-odemetutari)
```

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: Thanks for information

Comment: Can you provide sample data and expected output?  See [the top answer in this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056) for some great tips on how to format your question.

Comment: thanks for format i fixed question with learner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@learner 's solution not calculating properly because 2x times takes a.tutar.
I fixed it with cross join with this query, maybe for other programmers need here:

```
select a.adisoyadi,a.tckimlikno,(select  v1.tutar - v2.odemetutari as IcraBakiyesi from (Select   sum(tutar) as tutar from Om_icra_infos WHERE tckimlikno=tckimlikno ) as v1 CROSS JOIN (Select    sum(odemetutari) as odemetutari from Om_icraodeme_infos  WHERE tckimlikno=tckimlikno )as v2) as icraBakiyesi from
Om_icra_infos a join Om_icraodeme_infos b on a.tckimlikno=b.tckimlikno  group by a.tckimlikno,a.adisoyadi
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.tckimlikno,sum(tutar)-sum(odemetutari) as calculatedamount from
Om_icra_infos a join Om_icraodeme_infos b on a.tckimlikno=b.tckimlikno group by a.tckimlikno;

(or)

select t1.tckimlikno,IcraTutari-icraodeme as calculatedamount from
(SELECT  tckimlikno,sum(tutar) AS IcraTutari FROM Om_icra_infos where tckimlikno=tckimlikno  group by  tckimlikno)as t1 join 
(SELECT tckimlikno,sum(odemetutari) as icraodeme FROM Om_icraodeme_infos where tckimlikno=tckimlikno   group by  tckimlikno) as t2
on t1.tckimlikno=t2.tckimlikno groyup by t1.tckimlikno;
```

Comment: Thanks its working but calculating wrong answer i fixed it with cross join in last post check this.